# best way to get new access_token using PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting the error
"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user".
There seems to be tons of articles and ideas, but am very confused and it seems that things are changing as well. A lot say to use offline-access but that appears to be going away.
I did find [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/).

Does anyone have an example using the PHP SDK?

I tried doing something like the below but it does not seem to work; `$FBuser` is still zero:

```
$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                            "client_id=" . FB_APP_ID .
                            "&client_secret=" . FB_APP_SECRET .
                            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
list($name, $ACCESS_TOKEN) = explode("=", file_get_contents($token_url) );
$facebook->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
$FBuser = $facebook->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (change the scope parameter according with this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)):

```
// Checks if the user granted the access (after the redirection bellow)
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!$user) {
    // If not: Retrieves the login url in order to redirect the user
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_about_me', 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'));
    // redirect here (after accepting the user will be redirect back to the same url. In other words this script, that will check again if the user is authenticated)
} else {
    // Now the user is authenticated
    $user_data  = $facebook->api('/me');
    $user_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    // Saves the access token
}
```

Comment: This is a BAD way !
offline_access is deprecated ! `Please note: On October 3, 2012, the offline_access permission will be removed.`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: @Roni You down-voted just because of the offline_access? It's just a parameter it does not make the answer wrong -.-'

Comment: Great! you'r giving someone a bad example, not following Facebook Guidelines. and yes, the down vote is because "something along this lines" is not a good answer, if you wan't to help at least fix your code example.